# WARNING: Invalid Status code=403 text=Forbidden

Tags: java

When running a test with JAVA and selenium with the Chrome driver and the error appears:
WARNING: Invalid Status code=403 text=Forbidden
java.io.IOException: Invalid Status code=403 text=Forbidden.

I expected Chrome to open the page configured in the tests

Comment: Did you try to open that page in Chrome without doing anything else before that and with caches cleared? 403 means you (or your test) don't have the authorization to access the page which means you're either not sending any credentials (e.g. a token) - in which case you'd normally get a 401 though - or the wrong ones.

Comment: Yes, I access it via browser without any problems.
I did some tests with another URL like Google's and the same error is displayed.

Comment: I found the solution at this link:

https://medium.com/@thillaikayatk/how-to-fix-java-io-ioexception-invalid-status-code-403-text-forbidden-error-in-selenium-f8dedaf59e6f

Comment: When asking questions you have to provide significantly more details and be way clearer in how you ask your questions